# HttpContext.Current.RewritePath - to another domain - is this possible?

Tags: asp.net

Using ASP.Net is it possible to rewrite to a different domain using HttpContext.Current.RewritePath? Eg.

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("http://www.otherdomain.com");
```

When I try this I get the following exception:

'http://www.otherdomain.com' is not a valid virtual path

Answer (score 1):

`HttpContext.Current.RewritePath` is rewriting of the url on the server side.

It means that if you request the url `/products` you can tell to asp.net to rednder `/Products.aspx` by using:

```
if( HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl == "/products")
     HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/Products.aspx");
```

if you want to send the user to another domain you need to do:

HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.otherdomain.com/page");